# JavaScript Input not allowing decimals

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have this setting on my page to set an input automatically to 0 if the input is empty. However, the input does not allow me to enter [or recognise] a decimal/dot. Any ideas why this is happening and how to get around this?

```
const updateSettings = (e) => {
        if(e.target.value === '') {
            e.target.value = 0;
        } else {
            e.target.value -= 0;
        }
        dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_SETTINGS',
            setting: e.target.name,
            value: e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value
        })

<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value={settings.amount} onChange={(e) => updateSettings(e)} />
```

Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Kerron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3520119/kerron) for his feedback and pointing out why the issue was happening, however `defaultValue={0}` didn't work in my case and this is the solution that seems to work best for my scenario:

```
  if(e.target.value.charAt(0) == '0' && e.target.value > 0) {
       e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(1) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, when `target.value` is not empty, you try to minus `0` from it. When the value you enter is a `.` this isn't recognise as a valid operation as you're trying to minus a string that can't be parsed to a number (`.`) and a number (`0-9`).

I'm not sure why you need to minus `0` from `target.value`. Either way, if you get rid of your else block it should work.

edit - based on comment

I'm not sure of your exact use case, but there's a few ways you can handle the input field having a zero by default, and let the user replace it with their own value/s. You can use `setState` and pass that state to the `value` attribute, or you can use `defaultValue={0}`. Either one will allow the user to update the field normally.

Alternatively, you can set the `type` attribute to `number` and this will handle `0-9` and `.` as per your requirements.

What you can't have though is, making the input to always set to `0` when the input is empty (as in your `if` block), and not have a `0` at the start, given that the user won't be able to delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that initially, it works, however the 0 stays in front in addition to any other number I type in e.g 01.5 instead of 1.5 and the else block takes care of that issue